Why does my Node Modules Folder size is 600mb ? even though my Project is very small
Here are the all the dependencies in my project :
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.12.4",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

The node modules folder made by this dep are of size more tha 600mb ? i dont understand why does that happen , i am trying to make a project which has features like map(leaflet and leaflet-routing-machine) , notifications (firebase) and Router ( react-router-dom) these theree are the main modules but still with this less module my node modules file is of 600+mbs
I dont understand why it becomes this much heavy , i would love to know how can i know which dep is taking how much space in my node modules folder and what make it that heavy .

Welcome to the world of Javascript script development. This how it is! Javascript applications have a lot of large dependencies. These dependencies often offer a lot functionalities but in each project only a few of these functionalities is used.

definitely firebase is the heaviest one, do you need all the firebase services, because maybe you only need some of them, you can install a separate module like firebase/auth or firebase/firestore.
You can see all your dependencies there
